# How to implement function on pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, textacy

I'm trying to apply the `textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples` function to a pandas df column. The function returns empty generator objects, instead of subject_verb_object_triples when applied like so:

```
sp500news3['title'].apply(lambda x: textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples)
```

or

```
sp500news3['title'].apply(textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples)
```

I've also tried:

```
import spacy
import textacy
def extract_SVO1(text):
    new_doc = textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples(text)
    new_list = list(new_doc)
    text = new_list

sp500news3['title'] = sp500news3['title'].apply(extract_SVO1)
```

How can I implement the function on my dataframe column to return the correct function output?

Comment: You are not returning anything from your defined function.  You need to add a return statement to get assignments backt to your columns with apply.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples` returns a generator, which must be converted into some kind of iterable. Both your approaches are workable, but need some modification.

The first way: consume the generators

`sp500news3['title'].apply(lambda x: textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples).apply(pd.Series)`

The second way: write a separate function to apply

```
def extract_SVO1(text):
    new_doc = textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples(text)
    new_list = list(new_doc)
    return new_list
```